# ubuntu 16.04 apt package installation and dependences broken

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

i've try to install libc6_2.26-0ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb on my ubuntu 16.04 and broke apt installation after doing sudo apt-get -f install.
Now i can't install any package.

This is what i get when i try `sudo apt-get install aria2` for example

```
 Can't set locale; make sure $LC_* and $LANG are correct!
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = "en_US:",
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
Can't exec "locale": No such file or directory at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line 16.
Use of uninitialized value $Debconf::Encoding::charmap in scalar chomp at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line 17.
Setting up passwd (1:4.2-3.1ubuntu5.3) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/passwd.postinst: 21: /var/lib/dpkg/info/passwd.postinst: getent: not found
groupadd: group 'shadow' already exists
Group ID 42 has been allocated for the shadow group.  You have either
used 42 yourself or created a shadow group with a different ID.
Please correct this problem and reconfigure with dpkg --configure passwd''.

Note that both user and group IDs in the range 0-99 are globally
allocated by the Debian project and must be the same on every Debian
system.
dpkg: error processing package passwd (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 passwd
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I search on google and can't find how to resolve this. Help

Here is the end of /var/log/apt/history.log

```
Start-Date: 2019-05-01  16:38:47
Commandline: apt-get -u dist-upgrade
Requested-By: willy (1000)
Install: linux-modules-extra-4.4.0-145-generic:amd64 (4.4.0-145.171, automatic), python3-ndg-httpsclient:amd64 (0.4.2-1+certbot~xenial+1, automatic), linux-modules-4.4.0-145-generic:amd64 (4.4.0-145.171, automatic), linux-headers-4.4.0-145:amd64 (4.4.0-145.171, automatic), libc-bin:amd64 (2.23-0ubuntu10, automatic), linux-image-4.4.0-145-generic:amd64 (4.4.0-145.171, automatic), python3-pyasn1:amd64 (0.1.9-2+certbot~xenial+1, automatic), linux-headers-4.4.0-145-generic:amd64 (4.4.0-145.171, automatic)
Upgrade: libpolkit-gobject-1-0:amd64 (0.105-14.1ubuntu0.1, 0.105-14.1ubuntu0.5), libdns-export162:amd64 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.11, 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.14), libkrb5-3:amd64 (1.13.2+dfsg-5ubuntu2, 1.13.2+dfsg-5ubuntu2.1), libgssapi-krb5-2:amd64 (1.13.2+dfsg-5ubuntu2, 1.13.2+dfsg-5ubuntu2.1), libisccfg140:amd64 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.11, 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.14), libcups2:amd64 (2.1.3-4ubuntu0.5, 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.6), linux-headers-generic:amd64 (4.4.0.139.145, 4.4.0.145.153), ureadahead:amd64 (0.100.0-19, 0.100.0-19.1), php7.0-xmlrpc:amd64 (7.0.32-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.4), php7.0-cgi:amd64 (7.0.32-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.4), php7.0-cli:amd64 (7.0.32-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.4), libnss3-nssdb:amd64 (2:3.28.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.3, 2:3.28.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.5), libcurl3:amd64 (7.47.0-1ubuntu2.11, 7.47.0-1ubuntu2.12), python3-software-properties:amd64 (0.96.20.7, 0.96.20.8), openssl:amd64 (1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.13, 1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.15), ruby2.3:amd64 (2.3.1-2~16.04.11, 2.3.1-2~16.04.12), libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:amd64 (2.32.2-1ubuntu1.5, 2.32.2-1ubuntu1.6), git-man:amd64 (1:2.7.4-0ubuntu1.5, 1:2.7.4-0ubuntu1.6), php7.0-gd:amd64 (7.0.32-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.4), linux-image-generic:amd64 (4.4.0.139.145, 4.4.0.145.153), libgd3:amd64 (2.1.1-4ubuntu0.16.04.10, 2.1.1-4ubuntu0.16.04.11), libgs9:amd64 (9.25~dfsg+1-0ubuntu0.16.04.2, 9.26~dfsg+0-0ubuntu0.16.04.8), dovecot-lmtpd:amd64 (1:2.2.22-1ubuntu2.8, 1:2.2.22-1ubuntu2.10), dovecot-mysql:amd64 (1:2.2.22-1ubuntu2.8, 1:2.2.22-1ubuntu2.10), python3-josepy:amd64 (1.0.1-1+ubuntu16.04.1+certbot+7, 1.1.0-2+ubuntu16.04.1+certbot+1), nextcloud-client:amd64 (2.5.0-20181111.015125~xenial1, 2.5.2-20190319.015224~xenial1), mysql-server:amd64 (5.7.24-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 5.7.26-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), libsqlite3-0:amd64 (3.11.0-1ubuntu1, 3.11.0-1ubuntu1.1), libirs141:amd64 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.11, 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.14), certbot:amd64 (0.26.1-1+ubuntu16.04.1+certbot+2, 0.31.0-1+ubuntu16.04.1+certbot+1), bind9-host:amd64 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.11, 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.14), php7.0-opcache:amd64 (7.0.32-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.4), php7.0:amd64 (7.0.32-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.4), php7.0-pspell:amd64 (7.0.32-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.4), libavahi-common-data:amd64 (0.6.32~rc+dfsg-1ubuntu2.2, 0.6.32~rc+dfsg-1ubuntu2.3), dnsutils:amd64 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.11, 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.14), libavahi-common3:amd64 (0.6.32~rc+dfsg-1ubuntu2.2, 0.6.32~rc+dfsg-1ubuntu2.3), php7.0-recode:amd64 (7.0.32-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.4), apache2-suexec-pristine:amd64 (2.4.18-2ubuntu3.9, 2.4.18-2ubuntu3.10), console-setup-linux:amd64 (1.108ubuntu15.4, 1.108ubuntu15.5), php7.0-common:amd64 (7.0.32-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.4), git:amd64 (1:2.7.4-0ubuntu1.5, 1:2.7.4-0ubuntu1.6), openssh-sftp-server:amd64 (1:7.2p2-4ubuntu2.6, 1:7.2p2-4ubuntu2.8), libpolkit-agent-1-0:amd64 (0.105-14.1ubuntu0.1, 0.105-14.1ubuntu0.5), libk5crypto3:amd64 (1.13.2+dfsg-5ubuntu2, 1.13.2+dfsg-5ubuntu2.1), libisc160:amd64 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.11, 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.14), python-software-properties:amd64 (0.96.20.7, 0.96.20.8), console-setup:amd64 (1.108ubuntu15.4, 1.108ubuntu15.5), gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:amd64 (1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2, 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.3), dovecot-imapd:amd64 (1:2.2.22-1ubuntu2.8, 1:2.2.22-1ubuntu2.10), php7.0-sqlite3:amd64 (7.0.32-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.4), bind9utils:amd64 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.11, 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.14), libmagic1:amd64 (1:5.25-2ubuntu1.1, 1:5.25-2ubuntu1.2), dovecot-sieve:amd64 (1:2.2.22-1ubuntu2.8, 1:2.2.22-1ubuntu2.10), php-pear:amd64 (1:1.10.1+submodules+notgz-6, 1:1.10.1+submodules+notgz-6ubuntu0.1), php7.0-tidy:amd64 (7.0.32-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.4), rsyslog:amd64 (8.16.0-1ubuntu3, 8.16.0-1ubuntu3.1), dovecot-pop3d:amd64 (1:2.2.22-1ubuntu2.8, 1:2.2.22-1ubuntu2.10), libqt5webenginewidgets5:amd64 (5.6.4-1~xenial4, 5.6.4-1~xenial6), krb5-locales:amd64 (1.13.2+dfsg-5ubuntu2, 1.13.2+dfsg-5ubuntu2.1), libnextcloudsync0:amd64 (2.5.0-20181111.015125~xenial1, 2.5.2-20190319.015224~xenial1), libtiff5:amd64 (4.0.6-1ubuntu0.4, 4.0.6-1ubuntu0.6), php7.0-json:amd64 (7.0.32-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.4), dovecot-core:amd64 (1:2.2.22-1ubuntu2.8, 1:2.2.22-1ubuntu2.10), libisc-export160:amd64 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.11, 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.14), p7zip-full:amd64 (9.20.1~dfsg.1-4.2, 9.20.1~dfsg.1-4.2ubuntu0.1), libsasl2-modules:amd64 (2.1.26.dfsg1-14build1, 2.1.26.dfsg1-14ubuntu0.1), clamav-docs:amd64 (0.100.2+dfsg-1ubuntu0.16.04.1, 0.100.3+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), libruby2.3:amd64 (2.3.1-2~16.04.11, 2.3.1-2~16.04.12), php7.0-mbstring:amd64 (7.0.32-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.4), php7.0-readline:amd64 (7.0.32-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.4), php7.0-xml:amd64 (7.0.32-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.4), libkrb5support0:amd64 (1.13.2+dfsg-5ubuntu2, 1.13.2+dfsg-5ubuntu2.1), libqt5webengine-data:amd64 (5.6.4-1~xenial4, 5.6.4-1~xenial6), php7.0-xsl:amd64 (7.0.32-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.4), libcurl4-openssl-dev:amd64 (7.47.0-1ubuntu2.11, 7.47.0-1ubuntu2.12), php7.0-curl:amd64 (7.0.32-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.4), php7.0-zip:amd64 (7.0.32-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.4), liblwres141:amd64 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.11, 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.14), python3-acme:amd64 (0.26.0-1+ubuntu16.04.1+certbot+1, 0.31.0-1+ubuntu16.04.1+certbot+1), php7.0-ldap:amd64 (7.0.32-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.4), libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:amd64 (1.8.3-1ubuntu0.2, 1.8.3-1ubuntu0.3), distro-info-data:amd64 (0.28ubuntu0.9, 0.28ubuntu0.11), clamav:amd64 (0.100.2+dfsg-1ubuntu0.16.04.1, 0.100.3+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), php7.0-mcrypt:amd64 (7.0.32-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.4), ghostscript:amd64 (9.25~dfsg+1-0ubuntu0.16.04.2, 9.26~dfsg+0-0ubuntu0.16.04.8), php7.0-imap:amd64 (7.0.32-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.4), clamav-daemon:amd64 (0.100.2+dfsg-1ubuntu0.16.04.1, 0.100.3+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), clamdscan:amd64 (0.100.2+dfsg-1ubuntu0.16.04.1, 0.100.3+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), clamav-freshclam:amd64 (0.100.2+dfsg-1ubuntu0.16.04.1, 0.100.3+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), libpolkit-backend-1-0:amd64 (0.105-14.1ubuntu0.1, 0.105-14.1ubuntu0.5), openssh-server:amd64 (1:7.2p2-4ubuntu2.6, 1:7.2p2-4ubuntu2.8), iproute2:amd64 (4.3.0-1ubuntu3.16.04.3, 4.3.0-1ubuntu3.16.04.5), php7.0-intl:amd64 (7.0.32-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.4), libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common:amd64 (2.32.2-1ubuntu1.5, 2.32.2-1ubuntu1.6), openssh-client:amd64 (1:7.2p2-4ubuntu2.6, 1:7.2p2-4ubuntu2.8), python3-certbot-apache:amd64 (0.25.0-2+ubuntu16.04.1+certbot+1, 0.31.0-1+ubuntu16.04.1+certbot+1), libmysqlclient20:amd64 (5.7.24-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 5.7.26-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), libgs9-common:amd64 (9.25~dfsg+1-0ubuntu0.16.04.2, 9.26~dfsg+0-0ubuntu0.16.04.8), keyboard-configuration:amd64 (1.108ubuntu15.4, 1.108ubuntu15.5), bind9:amd64 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.11, 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.14), libdns162:amd64 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.11, 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.14), policykit-1:amd64 (0.105-14.1ubuntu0.1, 0.105-14.1ubuntu0.5), python3-certbot:amd64 (0.26.1-1+ubuntu16.04.1+certbot+2, 0.31.0-1+ubuntu16.04.1+certbot+1), file:amd64 (1:5.25-2ubuntu1.1, 1:5.25-2ubuntu1.2), pciutils:amd64 (1:3.3.1-1.1ubuntu1.2, 1:3.3.1-1.1ubuntu1.3), libqt5webenginecore5:amd64 (5.6.4-1~xenial4, 5.6.4-1~xenial6), unattended-upgrades:amd64 (0.90ubuntu0.9, 0.90ubuntu0.10), libnss3:amd64 (2:3.28.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.3, 2:3.28.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.5), libisccc140:amd64 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.11, 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.14), clamav-base:amd64 (0.100.2+dfsg-1ubuntu0.16.04.1, 0.100.3+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), wget:amd64 (1.17.1-1ubuntu1.4, 1.17.1-1ubuntu1.5), php7.0-soap:amd64 (7.0.32-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.4), linux-firmware:amd64 (1.157.20, 1.157.21), python-certbot-apache:amd64 (0.25.0-2+ubuntu16.04.1+certbot+1, 0.31.0-1+ubuntu16.04.1+certbot+1), libclamav7:amd64 (0.100.2+dfsg-1ubuntu0.16.04.1, 0.100.3+dfsg-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), apache2-doc:amd64 (2.4.18-2ubuntu3.9, 2.4.18-2ubuntu3.10), libbind9-140:amd64 (1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.11, 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-8ubuntu1.14), libpci3:amd64 (1:3.3.1-1.1ubuntu1.2, 1:3.3.1-1.1ubuntu1.3), nextcloud-client-l10n:amd64 (2.5.0-20181111.015125~xenial1, 2.5.2-20190319.015224~xenial1), libcupsimage2:amd64 (2.1.3-4ubuntu0.5, 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.6), libavahi-client3:amd64 (0.6.32~rc+dfsg-1ubuntu2.2, 0.6.32~rc+dfsg-1ubuntu2.3), curl:amd64 (7.47.0-1ubuntu2.11, 7.47.0-1ubuntu2.12), linux-generic:amd64 (4.4.0.139.145, 4.4.0.145.153), libapache2-mod-php7.0:amd64 (7.0.32-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.4), libcurl3-gnutls:amd64 (7.47.0-1ubuntu2.11, 7.47.0-1ubuntu2.12), libxslt1.1:amd64 (1.1.28-2.1ubuntu0.1, 1.1.28-2.1ubuntu0.2), php7.0-mysql:amd64 (7.0.32-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.4), tzdata:amd64 (2018g-0ubuntu0.16.04, 2019a-0ubuntu0.16.04), software-properties-common:amd64 (0.96.20.7, 0.96.20.8)
Downgrade: libmpx0:amd64 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11, 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10), libgcc-5-dev:amd64 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11, 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10), dbus-x11:amd64 (1.10.6-1ubuntu3.3, 1.10.6-1ubuntu3.1), libdbus-1-3:amd64 (1.10.6-1ubuntu3.3, 1.10.6-1ubuntu3.1), libapt-inst2.0:amd64 (1.2.31, 1.2.29ubuntu0.1), libldap-2.4-2:amd64 (2.4.42+dfsg-2ubuntu3.5, 2.4.42+dfsg-2ubuntu3.2), apt:amd64 (1.2.31, 1.2.29ubuntu0.1), cpp-5:amd64 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11, 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10), dbus:amd64 (1.10.6-1ubuntu3.3, 1.10.6-1ubuntu3.1), libkmod2:amd64 (22-1ubuntu5.2, 22-1ubuntu5), libitm1:amd64 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11, 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10), sudo:amd64 (1.8.16-0ubuntu1.5, 1.8.16-0ubuntu1.4), libc6:amd64 (2.26-0ubuntu2.1, 2.23-0ubuntu10), libcilkrts5:amd64 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11, 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10), passwd:amd64 (1:4.2-3.1ubuntu5.4, 1:4.2-3.1ubuntu5.3), libasan2:amd64 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11, 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10), libquadmath0:amd64 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11, 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10), isc-dhcp-common:amd64 (4.3.3-5ubuntu12.10, 4.3.3-5ubuntu12.9), amd64-microcode:amd64 (3.20180524.1~ubuntu0.16.04.2, 3.20180524.1~ubuntu0.16.04.1), libapt-pkg5.0:amd64 (1.2.31, 1.2.29ubuntu0.1), kmod:amd64 (22-1ubuntu5.2, 22-1ubuntu5), gcc-5-base:amd64 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11, 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10), libtsan0:amd64 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11, 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10), libubsan0:amd64 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11, 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10), gcc-5:amd64 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11, 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10), liblsan0:amd64 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11, 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10), libgomp1:amd64 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11, 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10), login:amd64 (1:4.2-3.1ubuntu5.4, 1:4.2-3.1ubuntu5.3), apt-utils:amd64 (1.2.31, 1.2.29ubuntu0.1), libgnutls30:amd64 (3.5.8-6ubuntu3, 3.4.10-4ubuntu1.3), libatomic1:amd64 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11, 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10), libtasn1-6:amd64 (4.12-2.1ubuntu0.1, 4.7-3ubuntu0.16.04.3), libcc1-0:amd64 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11, 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10), libstdc++6:amd64 (5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11, 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10), isc-dhcp-client:amd64 (4.3.3-5ubuntu12.10, 4.3.3-5ubuntu12.9), awstats:amd64 (7.4+dfsg-1ubuntu0.3, 7.4+dfsg-1ubuntu0.2)
Error: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
End-Date: 2019-05-01  16:38:53

Start-Date: 2019-05-01  16:39:14
Commandline: apt-get -f install
Requested-By: willy (1000)
Error: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
End-Date: 2019-05-01  16:39:21

Start-Date: 2019-05-01  16:39:53
Commandline: apt-get install libc6-i386
Requested-By: willy (1000)
Install: libc6-i386:amd64 (2.23-0ubuntu10)
Error: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
End-Date: 2019-05-01  16:39:53

Start-Date: 2019-05-01  16:50:13
Commandline: apt-get install aria2
Requested-By: willy (1000)
Install: libssh2-1:amd64 (1.5.0-2ubuntu0.1, automatic), aria2:amd64 (1.19.0-1build1)
Error: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
End-Date: 2019-05-01  16:50:13

Start-Date: 2019-05-01  16:55:15
Commandline: apt-get install locales
Requested-By: willy (1000)
Install: locales:amd64 (2.23-0ubuntu10), libc-bin:amd64 (2.23-0ubuntu10, automatic)
Error: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
End-Date: 2019-05-01  16:55:15

Start-Date: 2019-05-01  16:55:54
Commandline: apt install locales
Requested-By: willy (1000)
Install: locales:amd64 (2.23-0ubuntu10), libc-bin:amd64 (2.23-0ubuntu10, automatic)
Error: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
End-Date: 2019-05-01  16:55:54
```

When in run:  `grep -Ev '^#|^\s*$' /etc/apt/sources.list{,.d/*.list}` 
i get this:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://asi-fs-n.contabo.net/ubuntu xenial main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://asi-fs-n.contabo.net/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://asi-fs-n.contabo.net/ubuntu xenial universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://asi-fs-n.contabo.net/ubuntu xenial-updates universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://asi-fs-n.contabo.net/ubuntu xenial multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://asi-fs-n.contabo.net/ubuntu xenial-updates multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://asi-fs-n.contabo.net/ubuntu xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/certbot-ubuntu-certbot-xenial.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nextcloud-devs-ubuntu-client-xenial.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/nextcloud-devs/client/ubuntu xenial main
```

Comment: Can you paste the content of your `/var/log/apt/history.log` file starting from when you began messing with `libc`? `libc` is a vital package of your system and almost everything depends on it and requires it to have the correct version. Installing a different version breaks loads of applications and should not be done - basically ever. You will need to undo these actions and reinstall the correct older version.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I can't put the hole file content on the post. How can i share it?

Comment: I've edited the post and paste the latests log of the file.

Comment: to share the whole file, you can use https://paste.ubuntu.com/ for example.

Comment: Can you add the output of `grep -Ev '^#|^\s*$' /etc/apt/sources.list{,.d/*.list}`? That should show all your configured software sources. Also maybe upload your `/var/log/apt/term.log` log file somewhere which contains the complete apt outputs. That contains more detail than just the history.log

Comment: This is a link to /var/log/apt/term.log https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/KDb3zZVTxj/

Comment: Okay, so first of all download http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/libc6_2.23-0ubuntu10_amd64.deb and install that again with `sudo dpkg -i FILENAME.deb` to downgrade libc6 again to the correct version. You will also probably need to install http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/libc-bin_2.23-0ubuntu10_amd64.deb manually again first. Then try `sudo apt install ubuntu-minimal` and see what things still break.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ByteCommander this solve it

Comment: Good, I think there are still quite a few packages not installed that you had before, but at least the system should be functional again so that you can install them back when needed. Anyway, do an update cycle to be sure: `sudo apt update ; sudo apt upgrade` - if that works without problems too, you should be up and running again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sum up the fix we elaborated in the comments:

Your system was broken because you installed an incompatible version of `libc6`, a very important library on which half your system is depending on, many of those packages even requiring an exactly specific version. While trying to fix the conflicts, you uninstalled many more essential packages.

First of all you need to download the correct version of `libc6` again, which is [available from here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libc6) for Ubuntu 16.04 ([direct download of current `libc6` version for amd64](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/libc6_2.23-0ubuntu10_amd64.deb)).

Another essential package that got removed and which you see `apt` complaining about in the error messages ("getent" and "ldconfig" missing) is `libc-bin` that provides these required commands. You find it [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libc-bin) again for 16.04 ([direct download of current `libc-bin` version for amd64](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/libc-bin_2.23-0ubuntu10_amd64.deb)).

Install/downgrade both again manually with

```
sudo dpkg -i FILENAME.deb
```

Then try to install most of the remaining important packages again with

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-minimal
```

and see what things still break. If that was successful, try to get everything in shape and up to date:

```
sudo apt update ; sudo apt upgrade
```

After that ran successfully, your system should be in a functional and consistent state again.

For the future: *Never mess with essential system packages and don't blindly confirm when the package manager tries to remove important things!*